# Is there efficient SQL to query a portion of a large table

Tags: sql, performance

The typical way of selecting data is:

```
select * from my_table
```

But what if the table contains 10 million records and you only want records 300,010 to 300,020

Is there a way to create a SQL statement on Microsoft SQL that only gets 10 records at once?

E.g.

```
select * from my_table from records 300,010 to 300,020
```

This would be way more efficient than retrieving 10 million records across the network, storing them in the IIS server and then counting to the records you want.

Comment: The answers below led me to search for "SQL pagination" on Google. It seems MS SQL's syntax is pretty ugly for this see http://www.stillnetstudios.com/2008/11/12/pagination-mssql-2005/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at info about pagination. Here's a short summary of it for [SQL Server](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Pagination_In_SQL_Server_2005.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT * FROM my_table` is just the tip of the iceberg.  Assuming you're talking a table with an identity field for the primary key, you can just say:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ID >= 300010 AND ID <= 300020
```

You should also know that selecting * is considered poor practice in many circles.  They want you specify the exact column list.

Comment: There might be ordering in the query that would mean this would not work.

SELECT [columns] FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 300010
would be good if it existed

Comment: That's why I qualified the response with the primary key reference.

Comment: -1: too many assumptions: how do you know the primary key consists of a single column, or that it's even numeric? The query isn't usable if the user has deleted records, or wants them sorted differently, or wants them filtered on different criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. On MySQL and PostgreSQL (the two databases I've used), the syntax would be

```
SELECT [columns] FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 300010;
```

On MS SQL, it's something like `SELECT TOP 10 ...`; I don't know the syntax for offsetting the record list.

Note that you never want to use `SELECT *`; it's a maintenance nightmare if anything ever changes. This query, though, is going to be incredibly slow since your database will have to scan through and throw away the first 300,010 records to get to the 10 you want. It'll also be unpredictable, since you haven't told the database which order you want the records in.

This is the core of SQL: tell it which 10 records you want, identified by a key in a specific range, and the database will do its best to grab and return those records with minimal work. Look up any tutorial on SQL for more information on how it works.

Comment: Don't forget to user ORDER BY or you don't know what order you get the data in. With no ORDER BY the order is unspecified and can change between calls.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have an equivalent to MySQL's OFFSET keyword.

Answer (score 1):

When working with large tables, it is often a good idea to make use of Partitioning techniques available in SQL Server.

The rules of your partitition function typically dictate that only a range of data can reside within a given partition. You could split your partitions by date range or ID for example.

In order to select from a particular partition you would use a query similar to the following.

```
SELECT <Column Name1>…/* 
FROM <Table Name> 
WHERE $PARTITION.<Partition Function Name>(<Column Name>) = <Partition Number>
```

Take a look at the following white paper for more detailed infromation on partitioning in SQL Server 2005.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146.aspx

I hope this helps however please feel free to pose further questions.

Cheers, John

Answer (score 1):

I use wrapper queries to select the core query and then just isolate the ROW numbers that i wish to take from the query - this allows the SQL server to do all the heavy lifting inside the CORE query and just pass out the small amount of the table that i have requested. All you need to do is pass the [start_row_variable] and the [end_row_variable] into the SQL query.

NOTE: The order clause is specified OUTSIDE the core query [sql_order_clause]

w1 and w2 are TEMPORARY table created by the SQL server as the wrapper tables.

```
SELECT
    w1.*
FROM(   
    SELECT w2.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ([sql_order_clause]) AS ROW
    FROM (

        <!--- CORE QUERY START --->
        SELECT [columns]
        FROM [table_name]
        WHERE [sql_string]
        <!--- CORE QUERY END --->

   ) AS w2
) AS w1
WHERE ROW BETWEEN [start_row_variable] AND [end_row_variable]
```

This method has hugely optimized my database systems. It works very well.

IMPORTANT: Be sure to always explicitly specify only the exact columns you wish to retrieve in the core query as fetching unnecessary data in these CORE queries can cost you serious overhead

Answer (score -2):

Use TOP to select only a limited amont of rows like:

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM my_table WHERE ID >= 300010

Add an ORDER BY if you want the results in a particular order.

To be efficient there has to be an index on the ID column.